# Garmin autopilot question

Tags: general-aviation, autopilot

I recently took a check out in a Cessna 172 with a Garmin GFC 500. My instructor had said when the plane was turning on nav mode, to not select a different heading opposite of the turn and switch to heading mode. For example, the plane is making a right turn towards the east capturing a GPS track, is it a bad idea to select a north-northwest heading and switch from NAV mode to HDG? I don’t really see the problem with this.
Hopes this makes sense.

Comment: Why not ask the instructor what the reason is behind this guideline/procedure/technique/suggestion?

Comment: One reason that might be behind this is that it's maybe somewhat easier to inadvertently turn left when you intend to turn right or vice versa if the nav mode track and the new heading are close to 180º apart. But that's just a complete guess.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on what you consider to be a "problem".  The issue isn't unique to Garmin, most autopilots will immediately turn towards the heading or course of whatever source you have selected, so you just need to understand what will happen.

What will happen is this:   If the heading of the mode you switch to is less than 180° and opposite to the direction the airplane is already turning, it will reverse course in a turn to the new mode.  This reversal maybe a little bit rapid and startling if you aren't expecting it. Autopilots can be a bit jerky, and it could be disconcerting for passengers if your intent is to be smooth.

Even engaging heading from wings level can be jerky if the bug isn't at 12:00 on the HSI.

In the example you provided if your intent was to reverse your turn to a new heading to the north northwest, you'd probably want to disengage autopilot, level the wings, put the heading bug at the 12:00 position, and then engage heading mode. Then you could use the heading bug to smoothly turn the airplane to the new heading you want.

Alternately, if you wanted to leave autopilot engaged you could roll the heading bug 20 or 30° ahead of the direction of the turn, and then engage heading mode. The airplane will continue the right turn, then roll wings level when it gets to that heading.  Then you can gradually reverse the bug back the other direction to initiate a left turn to NNW.

Comment: Thank you for this information!!!! This does sound like it could be the answer. I’m meeting with the instructor tomorrow, and will definitely bring this up. I will update you on what he says about it.